# Combining lists with respect according to length of sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following two lists

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6}

{{1},{1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,3,4},{1,3,5}}
```

How can I thread both lists to obtain the following three lists

```
{{1,1},{2,1},{3,1},{4,1},{5,1},{6,1}}
{{3,2},{4,3},{5,3},{6,3}}
{{5,4},{6,5}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your first list has the form `Range[n]` then

```
b = {{1}, {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}};
Flatten[MapIndexed[{First[#2], #} &, b, {2}], {{2}, {1}}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}},  
>  {{3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}, {6, 3}},  
>  {{5, 4}, {6, 5}}}
> ```

Alternatively:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Flatten[MapThread[Thread@*List, {a, b}], {{2}, {1}}]
```

Comment: Can u generalize this answer with that simplicity to any type of list with single numbered values as its elements?

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
b = {{1}, {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}};

Inner[Thread[{##}] &, a, b, Flatten[{##}, {{2}, {1}}] &]
```

> {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}},
>    {{3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}, {6, 3}},
>   {{5, 4}, {6, 5}}}

Also

```
f1 = Flatten[#, {{2}, {1}}] &;
f2 = Thread /@ # &;
Composition[f1, f2, f1]@{a, b}
```

> {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}},
>     {{3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}, {6, 3}},
>   {{5, 4}, {6, 5}}}